# Users listed as still in frozen rooms

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, frozen-rooms

When a room is frozen and hidden, should all users be automatically removed so the room isn't listed on their profile?

The underlined room in the screenshot below is frozen and hidden, but GMan and myself were [still listed](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/65473#65473) as being in it.  The room isn't in the "rooms you're in" list; manually going to the room (how to do that won't be obvious for most users) and leaving seems to work.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really have strong feelings about this, but I found it somewhat nice to leave a short explanatory message ("There are already 20 million other jQuery rooms; please use one of those") in a room before freezing it. That way, the room creator can see it, and *then* leave on their own.

Several things to note:

1. Frozen rooms should very well be in the "rooms you're in" list; please double check your claim that this is not the case, because if true, this is a bug and not intended behavior.
2. While entering frozen rooms requires a few more clicks than entering a normal room, it's not forbidden. Assume your room was frozen automatically due to inactivity, and you make the case in a moderator flag that you'd like to have it unfrozen. Why should you not be waiting in there for the input box to reappear? And why should we auto-kick someone from a room they're allowed to be in?
3. We should probably special-case the "mine" tab in the rooms list; since that is pretty much the outside equivalent of the inside "rooms you're in" list, I guess it shouldn't default to hiding the frozen rooms like the other tabs.

**Edit** re 3: Frozen rooms are now visible by default on the "favorite" and "mine" tab; this should decrease the chance for confusion.

Comment: Re 1. I did not see it in the list before I left (before posting this question), but I am in several rooms.  This is a few days after it was frozen (I thought I had "left"), but I see now it was still marked as a favorite and then rejoined when I used rejoin all? Rejoining now does list it for me, in the "other rooms your in".

Comment: Re 2. I'm not saying it should be forbidden, but a hidden room not listed in your "rooms your in" list (as I thought was the case here) still being listed on your profile seems like a bug.

Comment: Re 3. I had not even thought to use that tab, I've been using the listing inside each room.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this was misunderstanding rather than a bug?

Comment: Only 20 million? Chat is really slowing down ...

Comment: @balpha: By the same token, should frozen/deleted rooms be shown by default on the favorites tab?  (Especially since "rejoin all" will rejoin them.)

Comment: @Roger Yes, I had the same thought. Probably makes sense.